# How to use awk to print specific string n time?

Tags: bash

For example:

```
cat file.txt| awk -F "\t" '{print $1}' | tr '\n' '\t' | awk -F "\t" '{print "Data_type" "\t" "Fraction \t" "Read \t" $1}'
```

I wanted to print "Fraction\t" "Reads \t" five times before $1.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cat` + `awk`, simply use `awk` [See Useless Use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

What is wrong with `awk '{print "Fraction\t Reads \t Fraction\t Reads \t Fraction\t Reads \t Fraction\t Reads \t Fraction\t Reads \t" $1}' file.txt` ?

Comment: Thanks!! Just wondering if there is an option makes awk print n times without typing the string repeatedly?

Comment: Sure :
`awk '{i=0; while (i<5) {printf "Fraction\t Reads\t"; ++i}; printf $1"\n"}' file.txt`